1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "2" already exists
hi how to fix this error if i need to search on any product i get this error
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "2" already exists.


This typically means you have some duplicated records in database. However, this could happen too due to some 3rd party code in your project. It is hard to trace
Anyways, I always thought throwing an exception for this reason is a bit strict. You can avoid it by applying this patch
diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php
index e69f7e7b..7d765283 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php
@@ -402,12 +402,6 @@ class Collection implements \IteratorAggregate, \Countable, ArrayInterface, Coll
         $itemId = $this->_getItemId($item);
 
         if ($itemId !== null) {
-            if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
-                //phpcs:ignore Magento2.Exceptions.DirectThrow
-                throw new \Exception(
-                    'Item (' . get_class($item) . ') with the same ID "' . $item->getId() . '" already exists.'
-                );
-            }
             $this->_items[$itemId] = $item;
         } else {
             $this->_addItem($item);

